# How can create table from result query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a new table from query result in SSMS:

Query result:

```
select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col3
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col1
order by col1 asc;
```

How can I create new table from above result:

I have tried

```
select *
into new_table
from (
    select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col3
    from table1
    inner join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col1
    order by col1 asc
);
```

I got the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Thanks

Comment: You need an alias if you use a sub-query... however you don't need a sub-query. Just add `into new_table` to your first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `order by` in your query -- as if you think that it makes a difference when you create the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so in general an `order by` is useless.

There are two cases where the `order by` makes sense.  One is with `TOP` and the other is when you have an identity column.  This suggests using [`identity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to add an identity column:

```
select identity(int) as id, table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col3
into new_table
from table1 inner join
     table2
     on table1.col1 = table2.col1
order by col1 asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select *
into new_table
from (
    select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col3
    from table1
    inner join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col1   
) s    -- alias here
order by col1 asc;  -- order by in the outermost query
-- tables by design are not ordered sets so the ORDER BY could be skipped
```

Comment: @DaleK In this context it is superfluous, when combined with TOP it may make sense

Comment: Regardless when using [`into`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) *Specifying an ORDER BY clause does not guarantee the rows are inserted in the specified order.* So redundant on two counts :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be

```
select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col3
Into new_table
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were using SQL Server and T-SQL code, I would use a Temporary Table to capture the result set. Temp Table is convenient since it doesn't require a schema definition in advance (like Table Variable). Temp Table will receive your result set as is, and can be queried after loading (within the scope of your work). Note the Hashtag syntax.

```sql
insert into #TempTable
select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col3
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col1
order by col1 asc;
```

Then...

```sql
select col1,col2,col3 from #TempTable
```

If you're not using T-SQL or SQL Server, I believe other SQL languages offer similar features.

Here's a helpful article:
https://www.sqlshack.com/when-to-use-temporary-tables-vs-table-variables/